# Netflix Conductor aws integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, netflix-conductor

Please, I would like to ask some questions related to Conductor and AWS.

I'm creating a new workflow where I will have a task that will send an SQS message to a microservice. I have some doubts:

- How to configure AWS Credential ID?
- How to configure AWS URL? For example, for testing with localstack.
- How do I configure Conductor Server to load contrib module via
  docker?
- How do I configure my task to send an SQS message to another
  microservice? Is the example below correct?

{
"sink": "sqs:buy-queue",
"asyncComplete": false
}

- How conductor knows the information about the account and region
  created for the queue? Example:
  https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/00534542333/buy-queue

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First edit /server/src/main/resources/application.properties (around line 60). The default queue type may be set to SQS, but we must enable the queues, and establish which AWS account is to be used:

```
conductor.default-event-queue.type=sqs
conductor.event-queues.sqs.enabled=true
conductor.event-queues.sqs.authorized-accounts={your AWS account number}
```

To add your credentials, add them via terminal:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="{key_id}"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="{access_key}"
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="{token_value}}"
``

I've written a post on how to configure Netflix Conductor to SQS queues with sample events, tasks and workflows:
https://orkes.io/content/docs/how-tos/Tasks/SQS-event-task
```